# How do I use JavaScript to add text to a field as the result of a radio button response? What can I add to the existing JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe

I'm using the JavaScript calculation in an Adobe Form to populate a field with a color. How can I also have text populate as a result of the radio button response? What can I add to this existing JavaScript (which is working great):

```
    var status = this.getField("Training").value;

    if (status == "No") {
          event.target.fillColor = color.yellow
        
     } else if(status == "Yes") {
          event.target.fillColor = color.green
     } else{
    event.target.fillColor = color.white
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer right after posting this of course. The answer is adding the code:

```
 event.value="add your text";
```

For example:

```
var status = this.getField("Training").value;

if (status == "No") {
    event.target.fillColor = color.yellow
    event.value="Proceed";

}else if(status == "Yes") {
    event.target.fillColor = color.green
 }else{
   event.target.fillColor = color.white
}
```